# How can I insert index for filtered data using apache Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to use Pig script to give index like 1, 2, ... to a filtered dataset/records, I'm loading in the table in a set format, so I can't add index/id when I load in. I've tried Rank function but it's not working under my corporates environment, and I can't use UDF. The current code is like this, and I want to insert index to **filterTable**.

```
table1 = LOAD 'tmp' using TransactionLoader(...);
filterTable = FOREACH table1 {
       rec = FILTER records BY (record MATCHES '.*\t2\t.*');
       GENERATE rec;
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't write an UDF,`Rank` is the only option `final = rank filterTable;`